# Yii::app()->db->createCommand() caching query results?

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii and I have a problem with `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()` that I run after inserting a row to table. I want to check how many rows I have in the table with params supplied, but `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()` returns 0 even if the row is inserted.

Here's the simplified code:

```
$photo_model    = new Photo();
$ehp_model      = new EventHasPhoto();

$photo_model->setIsNewRecord(true);
$photo_model->photo_id      = null;
$photo_model->original_id   = $data->id;

$photo_model->save();   

$ehp_model->setIsNewRecord(true);
$ehp_model->event_id    = $event_id;
$ehp_model->photo_id    = $photo_model->photo_id;
$ehp_model->is_approved = ($event_model->moderation == 1 ? -1 : 1);
$ehp_model->save(); 

$count  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('COUNT(p.photo_id) AS num')
    ->from('photo AS p')
    ->join('event_has_photo AS ehp','ehp.photo_id=p.photo_id')
    ->where('p.original_id="'.$data->id.'" AND ehp.event_id='.$event_id)
    ->queryAll();
$exist  = $count[0]["num"];  // exists is 0
```

Value of exists is 0, but when I run the same query through MySQL workbench I get 1, so I assume there's some built-in caching mechanism that's returning stale data.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error, with error reporting off.

If you don't pass `true` to queryAll, you will NOT get an associative array back; rather, you will get a result with integer index keys.

In other words, your `$count` variable contains:

```
$count = array(
    0=>array(0=>1)
)
```

With `error_reporting(`) set to 0, `$count[0]["num"]` evaluates to `false` in this situation.

To solve, pass `true` to `queryAll()`

```
$count  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('COUNT(p.photo_id) AS num')
    ->from('photo AS p')
    ->join('event_has_photo AS ehp','ehp.photo_id=p.photo_id')
    ->where('p.original_id="'.$data->id.'" AND ehp.event_id='.$event_id)
    ->queryAll(true);
$exist  = $count[0]["num"];
```

Or use `queryScalar()`

```
$count  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('COUNT(p.photo_id) AS num')
    ->from('photo AS p')
    ->join('event_has_photo AS ehp','ehp.photo_id=p.photo_id')
    ->where('p.original_id="'.$data->id.'" AND ehp.event_id='.$event_id)
    ->queryScalar();
$exist  = $count;
```

Or even access the correct array element using your original query:

```
$count  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('COUNT(p.photo_id) AS num')
    ->from('photo AS p')
    ->join('event_has_photo AS ehp','ehp.photo_id=p.photo_id')
    ->where('p.original_id="'.$data->id.'" AND ehp.event_id='.$event_id)
    ->queryAll();
$exist  = $count[0][0];
```